# Saving numbers to file and plotting them, in a loop

Tags: file, r, io

Given the following two loops, I want to save G.temp and S.temp to file and plot them at a later stage.

```
for(p in seq_along(time(S))){
  G.temp<-window(G,start = p,end=p+1)
  S.temp <- window(S,start=p,end=p)
  print(max(as.numeric(G.temp)-as.numeric(S.temp)))
  }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? If this is C++ code please let use know what you use to make this even compile ;)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read one of the introductions to R to learn about data types into which you can write your temporary results. Then use a standard function like `write.table` to export it.

Your installation of R came with [this introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html) which will also cover basic plotting questions.

For your second question, data import/export is covered in the [R Data Import/Export](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html) manual that also came with R.